# How to make nice curvy contour on high detailed (sculpted) mesh?

Tags: modeling, sculpting, sculpt

I run into the problem that I have quite irregular (bumpy) contour shapes from certain angles on my sculpted model.
So I have this form:

[image]
And I want to correct it to look something like this:

[image]

The only way I know in sculpting mode to adjust the form is the *grab* tool, but it is very hard and time consuming to solve this.

Comment: As this appears to be sculpted with dyntopo it's not so easy to work with as there's no way to temporarily turn off high details and work with low (as is possible with Multires) except for collapsing that area with Collapse mode which might be undesired due to details loss. In your case Smooth brush could work for smoothing the shape but it also removes details by averaging them on the surface. You could also try to create a small retopo of that area and shrinkwrap the highpoly on it (with vertex group) but it also is inefficient. There is Curve stroke mode for brush, maybe try if it works

Answer (score 0):

the reason of that resides on the actual geometry of your mesh, seems to have to many vertex and a very nested topology. I recomend you to try reduce your vertex acount from the beggining and use the subdivision surface modifier it'll round your shapes but it'll still will follow the topologhy. 
You can try to use remesh modifier or decimate modifier to reduce vertex number. But you'll loose all the sculpted allready details. 
good luck!